# Why is jquery height not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site where the menu bar and the footer are 50px height (On the image can you see what I want). Between the `nav` and `footer` I have a content `div` that need to take the other space so I want to use `Jquery` to get the document height, `Nav` height and `Footer` height and than substract them from each other (=content height) so than you get:

`content_height = document_height - nav_height - footer_height;`

the problem is that the height attribute give me 0  for both the `footer` and `nav`.

[image]

this is the jquery code I use:

```
var height = $(document).height();
var menu_height = $('#nav').height() + $('#footer').height();
$('#content').css('height', height - menu_height);
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/czs668se/2/). The strange thing is that the demo is working but my code isn't.

Does somebody know how to fix this so that i get the height of the object I want?

Comment: can you add your codes in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: can you also add the HTML?

Comment: That image hurts my eyes!

Comment: this should contain all the code http://jsfiddle.net/czs668se/. but on jsfiddle i get the right height. strange

Comment: numerous reasons they might be zero...css floats, css position , ajax loading etc. Provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: If it works in the jsfiddle then the problem is most likely that you call `$('#nav')` at the time when the element is not in the DOM. You should place your code inside of a DOM ready callback `$(function() {  /* ...your code ... */ });`

Comment: You can do such a layout with css only: http://jsfiddle.net/93enh76w/

Comment: thanks Nico O. that height:calc() thing worked. but I have one question? what means vh in calc(100vh - 100px);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the size of elements after the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var menu_height = $('#nav').height() + $('#footer').height();
    $('#content').css('height', height - menu_height);
});
```

Also note that `$(document).height()` is not equal to `$(window).height()`;

`$(window).height()` returns the height in pixel value of the (browser) window aka viewport.

`$(document).height()` returns the height in pixel value of the document being rendered.

Comment: getting the document (or window) height isn't the problem. the problem is getting the nav and footer height, that doesn't work.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: He probably doesn't wait for the document to load. Also the $(document).height() gives the height of the document even if you have vertical scrollbar. The $(window).height() gives the height of the viewport, which seems to be required in his case.

Comment: With your last edit. You got my `+1` back ;)

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   height = $(document).height();
   nav_height = $('#nav').height();
   footer_height = $('#footer').height();
   menu_height = (nav_height + footer_height);
   main_height = (height - menu_height);
   $('#content').height(main_height);
});
```

Comment: While the API of jQuery explains the use  `$(document).ready`  you should either give an explanation in your answer or at least link to the corresponding API page.

Comment: thanks. I'll do it for the next times :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ewd27sry/

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#content').height($(window).height() - ($('#nav').height() + $('#footer').height()));

});
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#nav, #footer {
    background: #ff0000;
    height: 50px;
}
#content {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle of the OP also worked so you should at least explain why your example will work outside of the fiddle environment.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use this to get the height `.contents().find('html').height()` if your nav and footer contains html this formula will be the best way to get the height. You can use it like this : `$('#nav').contents().find('html').height()`

Comment: and how would this help OP?

Comment: The `html` element is only valid at the root level. So it could **never** be a descendant of `#nav` and because of that  `$('#nav').contents().find('html').height()` will **always** return `null`.